# The Android APP crashes when the system WebView is being updated

Tags: android, webview, crash

The app is used as a launcher, and WebView is used in the app. However, the WebView component of the system is automatically updated, and when the WebView component is updated, the app crashes. Even if the app is not currently using the WebView component, as long as the app uses the WebView component, the app will crash. Is there any way to unload WebView class? Is there any way to avoid this crash?

Comment: Did you try [the workaround with `onRenderProcessGone`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303574/295004)?

Comment: Please share logs, this is too abstract.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no way for avoiding this crash. at any moment Play Store may start an update and when app gets update then in fact for some seconds it isn't available/installed and will cause crash in apps which are running and using this re-installed component. I'm facing this "architecture bug" for years, never found a solution...

Comment: I have an idea but I don't know if it is feasible: use a plug-in to integrate WebView, load the plug-in when the APP is in use, and uninstall the plug-in when the APP is not in use

Comment: You may try to cancel auto update on google play, i created a webview based application and it has been crash every two or three day, then i notice that i have auto update, i cancel it and now i think its ok.

Comment: yes, but say this to users, oftenly thousands and millions... Google should fix that in some way by own side, I've heard/read few approaches

Comment: Currently no working solution